# Redirect domain.com:81 to domain.com

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I really need to redirect `www.domain.com:81/site/` to `www.domain.com`. Previously I have used mod_rewrite, is it possible to solve this in a similar way?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices:

Using a htaccess file:

- `RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]`
- `Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/` Where 301 is permanent (302 temporarly)

Using php:

- `<?php header('Location: www.domain.com');`

Using html:

- `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.domain.com/">`

Using javascript:

- `document.location = "http://www.domain.com";`

pick one!

Comment: Thank you! I have tried with the htaccess alternative for a while now, but the website goes down every time I try. My old domain is www.domain.com:81/site/ and I want to point it to www.domain.com because of old bookmarks in peoples browsers.

Comment: Read the error log, it should tell you why. If you tried the rewriterule, you have to enable rewrite engine first.